# Merging 100gb dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two TSV files, both around 100GB.
I am simply trying to load and merge them and then export it to another TSV file.
Ofc I get a memory error (16GB RAM on my machine).

I thought of using the `chunksize` argument but even if I do - I expect that when I load both dataframes without a memory error the error will occur on the merging part where the merged df will be stored on my memory.

Can I also export the dataframe in chunks? meaning that right after I process 2 chunks from these 2 dataframe with merge I can export them to the file?

Just for clarity, a psuedo-code for that will look like

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(...., chunksize=1000)
df2 = pd.read_csv(...., chunksize=1000)

for a, b in zip(df1, df2):
    merge_and_export_to_csv (appending on every iteration)
```

Comment: Depends on how you are merging. For instance if it's an inner join vs outer join vs simple concat

Comment: @SerialLazer it is an inner join

Comment: That helps actually, but instead of a zip(df1, df2), I think you would need to do on a product. I hope the reason is quite clear